# Upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10 ceased at certain point: how to continue?

Tags: updates, flash

I upgraded my ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 through update manager, but with 30 minutes to go (out of 6 hours) I got 3 error messages telling me that it could not install these packages:

- firmware-b43-installer
- flashplugin-downloader: i386
- flashplugin-nstaller

(fyi: it's a x64 laptop).

So now I have a system which is not running very well (read: slow). When trying to update again, I see a message that it can do a partially distro upgrade due to an unfinished previous one. I try it but immediately it tells me that the system is updated without doing anything. So now I cannot get updates nether.

Is there a way to manually do the rest of the distro update, or should i burn an iso and do a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

Do a fresh install, it isn't worth the work you would have by trying to finish ugrading, and your system would probably get REALLY bugged...